# Select column in bar chart, echarts

Tags: bar-chart, pie-chart, echarts

Can I select column of bar-chart like pie-chart sector in this demo? https://www.echartsjs.com/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-rich-text

`selectedMode:` does not work for me here.

Comment: Did you found the answer?

Comment: It seems like they have not got such an option. This issue makes me think so https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/6813

Comment: Just checking further, will let you know if I could find anything.

Comment: Btw, I used custom styling for the column I wanted to select. You can catch the click event and determine the target column and then redraw the whole chart. Could not find other solution. At least it works :D